# Error in assigning latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am using mapkit and use thin code

```
    double      latitude1;
    double      longitude1;
@property (assign) double latitude1;
@property (assign) double longitude1;
```

latitude and longitude both in double type in database, But i recieved error when i write this line:(

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude  = [ classObj.latitude1 doubleValue];
        theCoordinate.longitude = [ classObj.longitude1 doubleValue];
```

this error is occur
"invalid recieve type double"
i have convert in float but it also didnot work..

Comment: Have you used @synthesize to generate the getter? And don't use assign for primitive types.

Comment: '@synthesize latitude1,longitude1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latitude1 property is already a plain double - you don't need (and can't use) doubleValue call with it. Just write:

```
theCoordinate.latitude  = classObj.latitude1;
```

Or even better

```
LLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(classObj.latitude1, classObj.longitude1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You define latitude1 and longitude1 are double

So, You can directly assign.

Like

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate.latitude  = classObj.latitude1;
theCoordinate.longitude = classObj.longitude1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[ classObj.latitude1 doubleValue] is Normally uses when typecasting required, but in  CLLocationCoordinate2D the latitude and longitude are double. No need to type-cast, just assign the value.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude  = classObj.latitude1;
        theCoordinate.longitude = classObj.longitude1;
```